# Jaspersoft/Pentaho - connect to MySQL via SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, pentaho, jasperserver, ssh-tunnel

I'm looking for a way to connect from my localhost:8081 (jasperserver) to a remote server, where my mysql DB is. I'm connecting to the DB through SSH (only way) in MySQL Workbench, it works good.
I did a lot of research, I found out I need to make a SSH Tunnel on my local machine, but how to do that? How to connect to my jasperserver via ssh? It gives me 'connection refused' when I try to ssh localhost:8081. I have installed openssh for windows.
I also tried the Pentaho, which works similar to jasper, and the connection method is the same.
Thanks...

Comment: What is the reason that you want to use `ssh`? Can't you reach the remote server directly since this should be the preferred way. If you need to do it due to security reasons you can establish `ssh` directly without having your local Pentaho server do it for you. Once the link is established ANY process can use the forwarded ports.

Comment: The thing is Ive been told ssh is the only way I can connect the DB. I cannot connect with host and user only. So I have to do this via ssh. And I can't figure out how to make that tunnel properly.

Comment: Can you establish an ssh connection to the remote server from a terminal?

Comment: Im using git repo on the same server via Git Bash commandline, connecting with ssh. I also have filezilla SFTP set up for that server, works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The way to correctly set up a tunnel is the following:

```
ssh <user>@<host that has access to database> -L <local port>:<db server>:<remote port>
```

Then you connect to `localhost:<local port>`.

Example: Your db server `db.mydomain.com` runs on port 3306 but you cannot access it. You first need to `ssh` to another machine, `myproxy.mydomain.com`, as user "username" which has access to port 3306 on the db server. On that machine, try

```
mysql -h db.mydomain.com -P 3306 -u <your db username> -p<your db password> <db name>
```

to verify the access to the db. Then you start by setting up the tunnel:

```
ssh username@myproxy.mydomain.com -L 3306:db.mydomain.com:3306
```

Once the SSH connection is established you can connect to your db by using the URL `localhost:3306` or `127.0.0.1:3306`.

What the tunnel is doing is redirecting traffic to port 3306 on your local machine to the remote db server's port 3306, using your proxy machine as a relay.

Comment: I am trying to access a database using SSH tunneling, credentials are fine, as i have tested this on MYSQL GUI Client, i have just tested the port fwding using command line and command line connection to server is also working perfectly.

But when i try to connect to the database server using pentaho it gives error as

Access denied for user 'stats'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I then used JNDI and gave the credentails there, but still it does not work.